# How to stop already playing sound and immediately start another

Tags: java, android, audio

When a sound that the user previously selected is playing, how can I stop that sound and immediately play the new selected sound?  The code I have so far only stops the new sound, but the user has to select the sound again in order to play it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.First);
        a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.firstsound);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        }
        );
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Second);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.secondsound);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        }
        );
```

I am making a soundboard with over 30 sounds, if that helps at all.  What (slight I assume) changes would I need to make to my code?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What functionality should buttons First and Second represent?

Comment: They play a sound when clicked on.  If button "First" was clicked initially, then when the user selects button "Second", the sound played by button "First" should stop and the the Second sound should start playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    public Boolean playing=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.First);
        a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                (playing)mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.firstsound);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                            playing=true;
            }

        });

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Second);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                (playing)mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.firstsound);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                            playing=true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check mediaPlayer if it null before stop it.`if(mediaPlayer != null &&   mediaPlayer.isPlaying) mediaPlayer.stop();`

Comment: @user2250122 if any of these answers helped you you could give back reputation, by accepting an answer (click green tick on the left) and/or upvoting an answer (click orange up arrow on the left). Good luck with your work! maurizio

Comment: Thank you!!  pietmau's code along with AwadKab's tweak did the trick!